# window.open creates new session

Tags: javascript, .net, session

This problem has been discussed various places, including SO forum. Unfortunately none of those threads I've seen has provided a solution really. When I launch a new browser window using the following (oxygen) code, a new session seems to be created for that window and all the session variables I need for processing the page are lost, resulting in NullReferenceExceptions down the line:

```
var Script: String;

Script:='[script language: "javascript"] var wdw=window.open(various parameters incl. the url:"anotherpageinthiswebsite.aspx?a=b"); wdw.focus(); [/script]' 

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( typeof(Page), 'List', Script);
```

I can swear I've used this method many times before, without a problem. It happens only on the production server, not during debugging on my own machine, both run .net v2 and I'm using IE for a browser. 
Any help would be highly appreciated,
best,

Comment: Can u verify that URL of the popup is in the same domain as opener page? Also, does production use any kind of load-balancer/webfarm?

Comment: Thanks Isabel for reaching out to me. I'll get back to you as soon as I'm back from vacation and in touch w production, a couple of weeks or so. Right now heading for the airport. Wish me a good vacation. Cheers,

Comment: Hi again, Isabel. Back from vacation now. I've checked on what you proposed, with a negative result, but in conjunction to doing so I discovered, embarrassingly, a very simple spelling mistake which through secondary effects lead to this behavior. So, problem kind-of solved by itself, but thanks for reaching out.

Comment: Still there? I thought this problem had gone away, but obviously it hasn't. I'm not sure if it appears intermittently or if I am just to disorganized to see the pattern here. In any case were back at the seemingly new session again. It certainly doesn't remember one single session parameter after I have done that window.open() exercise. Not in IE, that is. In firefox it works perfectly alright. That give a hint?

Comment: To be precise, the code driving the content in that new window cannot access any session parameter. The mother window, as it were, is still OK, with all session parameters intact.